# Which word, 'when' or 'where,' is more appropriate to describe 'stage' in the following sentence?

Tags: word-choice

> Urbanization is at the stage when most people are aware of the central importance of infrastructure.

> Urbanization is at the stage where most people are aware of the central importance of infrastructure.

Which is better to use 'when' or 'where' in both sentences and why? In my opinion, 'stage' indicates a period, i'm uncertain which word is more suitable.

Comment: Urbanization isn’t a stage.

Comment: @Xanne It seems that in the context of the evolution from Third World country to industrialized country the term "[urbanization stage](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22urbanization%20stage%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)" is indeed fairly well defined. It is found in the discourse of numerous Asian writers, but not only: (1/2)

Comment: @Xanne ([Territory and Administration in Europe  — Robert John Bennett · 1989](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Territory_and_Administration_in_Europe/RKGNAAAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22urbanization+stage%22&dq=%22urbanization+stage%22&printsec=frontcover)) "The urbanization stage is one in which the dispersion of people and workplaces further increases and there becomes established a settlement structure associated with the so - called post - industrial city". (2/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a truly better choice between "when" and "where". Both are used, and "where" has come to be significantly more frequent only lately. The ngram below shows that.

[image]

Nevertheless, the use of  these two relative adverbs does not make for the most elegant formulation; it has a somewhat colloquial quality. The following wording is a possibility among many that will carry the same meaning.

- Urbanization is the stage characterized by the general awareness of the  central importance of infrastructure.

Comment: The ngrams for 'is **at** the stage when/where' are pretty similar. // The locative senses of 'where' predate the temporal, so 'when' involves the 'time represented linearly' metaphor.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I must say that I relate with difficulty to the idea of a metaphor and even more so to that of time as the "arrow" of time;  "when people meet" implies an indefinite number of simultaneous occurrences of people meeting, at various times. It seems that more abstraction is needed to account for this usage; in the words of Quirk et al., "the meaning of several subordinators that  primarily  express time, place, or condition may be _neutralized_ […] to convey a notion of recurrent or habitual contingency: _when, whenever, once, where, whrever, if_".